# Thymeleaf 2 expressions in URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE , Thymeleaf 3.0.11.RELEASE .
I have

```
<a class="k-button" th:href="@{/customer/view/{id}(id=${accountObject.id})}" style="min-width: 0; color: green;" title="Xem"><span class="k-icon k-i-preview"></span></a>
```

It works ok, generate to `http://localhost:8080/customer/42`.
I try

```
<a class="k-button" th:href="@{/customer/view/{type}(type=${accountObject.accountObjectType})/{id}(id=${accountObject.id})}" style="min-width: 0; color: green;" title="Xem"><span class="k-icon k-i-preview"></span></a>
```

It does not work as expected, I want it generate to `http://localhost:8080/customer/1/42` (`accountObject.accountObjectType` = `2`)

I need something like `/customer/1/` because it will be `@PathVariable("type") Integer type` in Spring MVC Controller.

How to put 2 expressions in Thymeleaf URL?

Comment: Put all the parameters in a single set of parentheses at the end, comma separated.

Comment: thank you, it work. Please post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple placeholders in a URI template; provide all the substitutions at once at the end. It should look something like this:

```
th:href="@{/customer/view/{type}/{id}(type=${accountObject.accountObjectType},id=${accountObject.id})}"
```

(I also think you probably don't need the `{}` for each substitution value, but it won't hurt.)